# I dont get DB normalization - isn't repeating FKs also repeating?

Tags: sql, database, normalization

Well, I have just heard about that today but I do not get it. So I should not have Transaction table with Date column (because more transactions can occur at the same day) but I should have a Transaction and a Date column, where a Date would have a FK to a transaction. What is the point then, instead of a date I will repeat FK.

an example: A broker can make a transaction at any date. (transaction then needs to hold broker and date information).

Comment: It's clear at all what the 2 different designs that you are comparing are. Add details, table structures, columns, FKs, etc.

Comment: @ypercube: `s/it's clear/it's not clear/` ?

Comment: @BillKarwin Sorry, I meant **not clear at all**. But now I can't edit.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Transaction date does not need to be normalized.

But, imagine that Transaction is tied to customers, and customer details also have to be kept - this is a case where normalization helps to reduce data redundancy.

Comment: If there are other transaction details depending on date, then it may still be normalized. Are there other transaction details which depend on the date?

Comment: There are three tables: Broker, Transaction and Date. Transaction should contain broker ID and date (FK?).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date table is like the period table in our data warehouse, it is probably structured something like this:

```
Field date, datatype date (not datetime) primary key
other fields include fiscal year and holiday information
```

Then your transaction table might resemble something like this:

```
broker_id, foreign key to broker
date, foreign key to date
transaction time
other fields as necessary
```

Your question was, "what's the point?".  This sort of database design allows you to easily answer questions like, "give me broker x's stats for the past 5 fiscal years, broken down by fiscal period"

Comment: but this foreign key to broker is actually a column, correct? Sorry, I'm new to this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing scalar values (dates, numbers, etc.) is generally overkill.  Just because values repeat doesn't mean they should be normalized out.  Only repeating values *that aren't directly related to the row's primary key* (e.g. an Address) should be candidates for normalization.

The only benefit I can see to normalizing dates if you want to add different *representations* of each date (e.g. Month, Quarter, etc.) without having to do the math each time.  Otherwise the drwabacks outweigh the advantages in my opinion.

Comment: Scalar attributes with repeating values absolutely *are* candidates for normalization and generally *should* always be normalized. That doesn't mean they need to be decomposed into new relations though. I think that's what you meant but it's not what you said. *Normalization* is not just a synonym for *decomposition*.

Answer (score 1):

Moving a date attribute into another table and making it a foreign key in the Transaction table has nothing to do with "normalization".
Consider the example relation:

```
T{TransactionId,Date}
```

and dependency

`{TransactionId}->{Date}`

If TransactionId is a key then T already satisifies 6th Normal Form. Moving Date into another table, replacing it with another attribute and/or making it a foreign key will not make T any "more normalized" than it is already.

Whether or not attribute values "repeat" is irrelevant in normalization. What matter are the functional dependencies and join dependencies you mean to satisfy in your database schema. "Repeating data" is a phrase sometimes used *informally* to describe what functional dependencies are about but it is an oversimplification to say that decomposition is required simply because data repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Using the date is not an ideal example. Think instead of customer records, tied to each transaction. You want to store the FK of a customer within each transaction row. You don't want to store the customer's name, address, password repeatedly though!